# Daily planner app

Tags: windows, android, planning

I am looking for a daily planner app which fulfills the following criteria:

- Synchronization to Google Calendar etc. is not mandatory in the app;
- The app doesn't revolve around tasks and to-do lists, entries can be added which don't need to be checked off as completed or remain uncompleted;
- The app doesn't revolve around time tracking - my emphasis is on planning, not tracking;
- There is a "day view" which graphically depicts a single day with entries in it; it's not just a list of entries because each entry has to have a start and end time visible and any time gaps between entries also need to be shown;
- Entries can be added by dragging from the start time to the end time;
- There is also a "week view", where 7 "day views" are grouped side by side;
- It's not mandatory that the entries should be recurring periodically;
- Entries can be categorized;
- There is an Android version and a Windows version;
- User interface is visually attractive, e.g. Material Design and does not look like a website from the '90s.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: By "PC version", are we to assume Windows? And by "Mobile", Android?

Comment: Yes! I will edit the post to add those details, sorry

Comment: No problem, since you are new (did you read [ask]?). I added those tags for you. The more details you give, the more likely you are to get an answer. Btw, if you want it to free, add the [tag:gratis] tag; otherwise, state a budget